# my code which i written it throws me an Invalid syntax error at try:

Tags: python, ray

I have tried to do it without def and that worked this is the code i dont really know what to do i tried to give indentation correctly also

But when i run this it throws the error invalid syntax

````
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
try:
    Func1()
except:
    pass



ray.get([func1.remote()])



def func1():
    for i in range (99999):
        print("h")```

The error is invalid syntax at try:




This is the code that worked for me 


try:
    do_something()
except:
    pass
````

Comment: Thanks bro soo fast u replied i didnt saw that

Comment: Done thans alot :)

Comment: def func2():
    try:
     funcc2()
    except:
     pass


def Fu1():
 for i in range (100000000000):
  os.remove('path')
This quits early doesnt loop

Comment: Hi @Anoobcoder, as the question asked about the SyntaxError, for which I mentioned the fix in my answer, also now  the code not running is probably out of scope of this question. Perhaps you can create another question, add more details there and people more familiar with ray can help you out. Sorry If I cannot be of much help here

Comment: Also you can only remove a path once. You cannot do it multiple times since once a file is removed from the path and you try to remove it again, it will throw an exception

Comment: no problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a decorator like `@ray.remote` on top of a `try/except`, which causes the `SyntaxError`.

You need to wrap your try/except around a function, and decorate that function. For example

```
@ray.remote
def Func2():
    try:
        Func1()
    except:
        pass
```